# Markdown with unicode bullets / itemization marks

Tags: unicode, markdown

I use a keyboard layout (Neo 2), which lets me directly enter lots of unicode characters – like for example `•` (U+2022, “bullet”), `–` (U+2013, “en dash”) and `—` (U+2014, “em dash”).

I’d like to use these characters in markdown files. Raw MD files then would already look halfway marked-up and I’m already very much used to type those characters. Are there Markdown dialects which support this?

Comment: most markdown implementations (e.g. pandoc) are unicode-aware, so the characters will be passed through just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are currently (2019) *no* Markdown dialects that support Unicode list-item markers, such as the "bullet": •.

The reference for that claim is [Babelmark](https://babelmark.github.io), a GitHub-hosted tool for comparing the output of various Markdown implementations. As of this writing, the Markdown source

```
• item 1
• item 2
```

is [rendered as a regular paragraph of text](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%E2%80%A2+item+1%0A%E2%80%A2+item+2), not a list, by all of the 35 Markdown implementations the tool incorporates — which, arguably, are *all* implementations of practical relevance. The on-screen output of the above would typically look like this:

```
• item 1 • item 2
```

Of note in this particular context is that Markdown inventor John Gruber considers the lack of support for the *actual* bullet • to denote *bulleted* lists a “glaring omission”. In a [blog post from 2017](https://daringfireball.net/2017/07/unordered_lists_in_markdown) he goes on to explain that, when he worked on the first Markdown parser back in 2003, he *would* have included Unicode syntax markers, first and foremost • for lists, had it not been for character-encoding mismatches, a frequent real-world issue at the time, which is why he restricted the special characters to the 7-bit ASCII range.

[CommonMark](https://commonmark.org), the post-hoc standardization effort for Markdown syntax, has not included •. A lengthy and sometimes heated [discussion on this very topic](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/unicode-character-bullet-u-2022/397) has been going on its message board since 2014, with contributions from some of CommonMark's most prominent proponents. The last word, however, may yet be spoken, as the finalized 1.0 specification still awaits publication.

[reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists), for what it's worth, a text-file format with a minimal-markup design philosophy very similar to Markdown's, *does* have support for Unicode list markers (•, but also ‣ and ⁃), which was [added in 2006](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/mailman/message/9699983/).